# I can't get rid of dual boot option on Windows 10 after installing Remix OS in an external hard drive

Tags: windows-10, boot

A friend of mine brought me an old hard disk in which he wanted me to install remix os on, we plugged it in my pc (using a USB adapter), installed Remix Os (choosing hard disk option) then unplugged the disk (he went home, didn't like the OS and ended up formatting the whole disk).

Now whenever i turn on my computer, i get this : 
[image]

Msconfig-> boot have don't have any trace of RemixOs :

[image]

And neither does the Startup and Recovery in Advanced system settings :

[image]

what can i do to solve this please ?

thanks

**Edit**
bcdedit shows RemixOS : 
[image]

Comment: The dual boot isn't managed by Windows. Windows bootloaders can only manage other Windows installations.

Comment: @MichaelBay so you mean that the only way to fix this is by properly uninstalling remixOs ? also please check the edit, bcdEdit shows RemixOs in the boot manager, i tried the BcdEdit remove entry using remixOs UDID but then my computer won't boot at all (thankfully i created a backup file and re-imported it when the system couldn't boot)

Comment: I don't know about RemixOS other than it's an "Android Desktop OS" but I know a lot about dual booting with Linux based OSes. You're lucky because you have a UEFI system. In the old days with BIOS/MBR you'd now be needing a Windows installation media to boot from and repair the bootloader (reinstall the Windows bootloader to MBR) but with UEFI you can boot all OSes independently: Just open the UEFI settings, boot settings, and give first priority to the Windows bootloader manager that is still there and it'll boot Windows directly.

Answer (score 1):

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \efi\microsoft\boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Solved the issue.

Comment: Of course it did but that was unnecessary, as commented above.